# How do you programmatically create a download link for a transformed asset in Cloudinary?

Tags: cloudinary

I really like Cloudinary, I was able to do anything I wanted, but I am missing one thing.

I have a flow where I upload photos, and I make 2 transformations for each upload.

For the original photo I was able to create a download link

```
return this.imageManager.utils.private_download_url(publicId, 'jpg', {
  resource_type: 'image',
  type: 'private',
  expires_at: (Date.now() / 1000) + expirationTimeInSecs,
  attachment
})
```

I am trying to achieve the following, I want to create a download link for one of the transformed assets. I have tried different ways, but I was not able to do it.

Finally I read the [following answer](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4407433413010-Outcoming-transformation), which was made some time ago, I am not sure if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private download URL was not designed to retrieve a derived version, it was only designed to download the original. With that being said, token/cookie-based authentication would be the way to go.